# Value returned before assigned in subscribe

Tags: angular, subscribe

I need to return a value from subscribe since I cannot set in a global variable.
However, the function always returns before the value is assigned the data from the subscribe.
I tried all the answers suggested in posts in the topic but it didn't work

```
getMessage(field): string {
  this.service.getMessage(field).subscribe(mssg => {
    let message = '';
    message = mssg;
    return message;
  });
}
```

The calling function: (It's called several times in the component)
it's inside setting values for angular material table

```
something like


    const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
      {position: 1, name: data?
this.getMessage(obj) + ' ' + someobj.id
, weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
      {position: 2,  name: ess?
this.getMessage(se) + ' ' + yy.gt, weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
    ,
    ];
```

Comment: How do you use that value? Depending on your use case, you might be able to use an `async` pipe. And if that's not applicable, you can always wait for the backend call to finish before processing the response.

Comment: added to description of quesiton

Answer (score 1):

You have not understood well how this works.

Your `return` statement returns the value in the `subscribe` function. It does not return the value in the function. Actually, your function returns void.

You have no way of returning an asynchronous value synchronously.

What you should do instead is this :

```js
getMessage(field): Observable<string> {
  return this.service.getMessage();
}

// Somewhere else

this.getMessage('myField').subscribe(() => {
  // Do what you want here
});
```

Comment: well he can use `toPromise()` to transform an observable to a promise then use async await to return the value, that's still work, right?

Comment: That's not synchronous, it's still a promise. Using `async/await` transforms the calling function into an asynchronous function. What you end up doing is converting all synchronous functions into asynchronous functions. I'm not against it, but if you want a true solution, I would instead take the approach I described !

Comment: Yes I'm not against you, i'm fully understand, my point is just if he still want the function return something, he can do that way

Comment: I understand that too, what I'm a trying to say is that if the calling function returns a `string`, then using `async/await` will make it return `Promise<string>`. So he'll have to edit the function above that, and so on. Totally a valid solution, it really depends on the context ! (you should make an answer too by the way)

Comment: Well, sorry for already posting the same answer you discussed here. I only saw your discussion, once I posted it already.

Comment: @FabianStrathaus Totally fine bro

Comment: I am not sure how it can be integrated to my use case.
Can you look at my edited question?
Thanks

Comment: That is not clear at all. Please provide a [mcve] if you wish to have more help !

Comment: is it clearer? i added a new example

Answer (score -1):

Just to complete possible options:
You can also "convert" your observable to a promise using `lastValueFrom` from `rxjs` package (only makes sense if your observable is only emitting one value) and using an async function (which can be "awaited" by the consumer):

```
async getMessage(field): Promise<string> {
  return lastValueFrom(this.service.getMessage(field));
}
```

Comment: Thanks
In my case i don't think it will be possible to implement